# Do I have to suppose the function to be surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is not a question on how to prove the result

In proposition 1.2. of Atiyah's Introduction to Conmutative Algebra it says:

Let $A$ be a non trivial ring. The following are equivalent:

i) $A$ is a field

ii) $(0)$ and $(1)$ are the only ideals of $A$

iii) Every homomorphism from $A$ to a non trivial ring $B$ is injective

The problem here is with the translation. The spanish edition says "homomorfismo de $A$ en un anillo no nulo $B$" which may be understood as "homomorphism from $A$ onto a non trivial ring $B$" or "homomorphism from $A$ to a non trivial ring $B$".

I could only prove the proposition supposing the "onto" part and the book also does so. Does the english edition say "onto"?

Comment: Onto is not necessary.  The proof considers the kernel of the homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surjectivity is immaterial, in this case. Since ring homomorphisms are assumed to send $1$ to $1,$ then $1$ cannot be in the kernel of the homomorphism. Thus, if $(0)$ and $(1)$ are the only ideals of $A,$ then $(0)$ must be the kernel of the homomorphism, and so it is injective.

**Added**: We *may* assume surjectivity without loss of generality, and it sounds like Atiyah does. Suppose all surjective homomorphisms from $A$ are injective. Now take an arbitrary homomorphism $f:A\to B,$  for some ring $B.$ The image of $A$ under $f$ is a subring of $B,$ say $C.$ Then $g:A\to C$ defined by $g(x):=f(x)$ for all $x\in A$  is a surjective homomorphism $A\to C.$ Thus, $g$ is injective by hypothesis, and so $f$ is injective, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you assume a nontrivial homomorphism, it must be mentioned onto. Because every homomorphism from a field to a ring is either one one or maps everything to 0.

Comment: Well, if $1$ is included in the ring structure, a homomorphism should also preserve it.

Comment: OK it is assumed in Atiya's book. I forgot. But many authors don't assume it.